# Visual Basic 6 and UNC Paths

Tags: vb6, unc

I'm receiving feedback from a developer that "The only way visual basic (6) can deal with a UNC path is to map it to a drive."  Is this accurate?  And, if so, what's the underlying issue and are there any alternatives other than a mapped drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way that works.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject ' Add Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    MsgBox fs.FileExists("\\server\folder\file.ext")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

We have a legacy VB6 app that uses UNC to build a connection string, so I know VB6 can do it.  Often, you'll find permissions problems to be the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Even the old school type of file handling does work:

```
Open "\\host\share\file.txt" For Input As #1
Dim sTmp
Line Input #1, sTmp
MsgBox sTmp
Close #1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is True, if you are using the `Scripting.Runtime` library.

Oldschool VB had some language constructs for file handling. These are evil. Don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

In VB6 you cannot use CHDrive to a UNC path.

Since App.Path returns a UNC path, attempting to use ChDrive to this path, `ChDrive App.Path` will cause an error.

As Microsoft say "ChDrive cannot handle UNC paths, and thus raises an error when App.Path returns one". For more information, look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263345(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What sort of file I/O are you doing?  If it's text, look into using a FileSystemObject.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed VB6 UNC path issues when a combination of the items below exist:

- the unc points to a hidden '$' share
- the server name exceeds 8 chars and or has non standard chars
- a portion of the path is exceptionally long
- the server has 8.3 support turned of for performance purposes

Usually a 75 path file access error or 54. At times this may be related to API's such as getshortfilename and getshortpathname on the aforementioned UNC's.

Other than that they work great... A mapped path will usually not have these issues but those darned drive mappings disconnect often and can change at anytime causing many support headaches.